# Route in laravel with array don't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i have created a new category `games` for my site. The site had two existing categories called `movies` and `series`

The fallowing code displays a list under the entrie with routing genre titles.

```
<a href="{{ route(($title->type == 'series' ? $title->type : $title->type.'s').'.index').'?genre='.trim($genre) }}">{{ $genre }}</a>
```

now i need to add `games` to this code. I tried it with an `array`

```
<a href="{{ route(($title->type = array('series', 'games') ? $title->type : $title->type.'s').'.index').'?genre='.trim($genre) }}">{{ $genre }}</a>
```

but the code doesent work. im getting an error with this array on all sites, if i change series to `games` the `game` and `movie` site with his entries works fine.

Comment: You can't do `$title->type == array(..)`. Look at `in_array()` http://php.net/in_array instead.

Comment: thank you for comment but i solved it with @if ($title->type == 'series')
                        @ include('Titles.Partials.DetailsPanel')
                    @ else
                    @ include('Titles.Partials.DetailsGamesPanel')
                    @ endif